# Multiple environment testing with jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, jestjs, e2e-testing

I have some environment variables in my React app placed in `.env.development` file, which change application logic and view, for example: `REACT_APP_USER_SIGN_UP_ENABLED=true`.

Can I configure Jest config or certain tests for testing each scenarios, where `REACT_APP_USER_SIGN_UP_ENABLED=true` and `REACT_APP_USER_SIGN_UP_ENABLED=false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily change env variables with

```
process.env.VARIABLE_TO_CHANGE = 'newvalue'
```

Here's a quick demo of it in action:

**.env**

```
ENV_VARIABLE=value
```

**EnvReader.js**

```
const read = () => {
    return process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
}

module.exports = {
    read
}
```

**EnvReader.test.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const read = require('./EnvReader').read

describe('tests', () => {
    it('can read environment variables', () => {
        expect(read()).toEqual('value')
    })

    describe('by changing environment variables', () => {
        let originalValue

        beforeAll(() => {
            originalValue = process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
            process.env.ENV_VARIABLE = 'othervalue'
        })

        afterAll(() => {
            process.env.ENV_VARIABLE = originalValue
        })

        it('can read the new value', () => {
            expect(read()).toEqual('othervalue')
        })
    })

    describe('after messing with environment variables', () => {
        it('can still read the original value', () => {
            expect(read()).toEqual('value')
        })
    })
})
```